# Ошибка с подключением стилей в sass

Tags: css, angular2, шрифты, sass

Привет!Я начал изучать Angular и решил сделать приложение на нем и мне понадобилось подключить шрифты

```
@import "fontello.scss"


@font-face
    font-family: 'latoblack'
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.eot')
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@font-face
    font-family: 'latobold'
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.eot')
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@font-face
    font-family: 'latoitalic'
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot')
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@font-face
    font-family: 'latolight'
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoLight/lato-light.eot')
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoLight/lato-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoLight/lato-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoLight/lato-light.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@font-face
    font-family: 'latoregular'
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoRegular/lato-regular.eot')
    src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoRegular/lato-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoRegular/lato-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoRegular/lato-regular.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal
```

Использовал синтаксис Sass встроенный в AngularClI `--style=sass`.Но я получил ошибку.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.sass
Module build failed:
         url('../assets/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.woff') format('woff'),
        ^
      Property "url" must be followed by a ':'
      in X:\projects\BranD\src\app\app.component.sass (line 8, column 10)
```

Можете подсказать в чем я ошибся и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3):

везде перед  `url` поставить `src:`